# Is a laminated Birth Certificate copy acceptable for travel?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork

My mother and I have different surnames so immigration officers often ask for a birth certificate. When leaving Russia, on Russian passports, the officer made a fuss that the certificate was laminated and not an original. Is this acceptable to travel with a laminated non-original copy? Do I need to take the original just in case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this will be accepted for travel but it isn’t recommended.

It’s best not to laminate your card. Laminated cards make it difficult, if not impossible, to detect important security features.

Taking the original could help in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

When issuing the birth certificate, the guidance used to be to laminate it. Now, this guidance has been changed.

If you are a child, beware as when applying for a Russian internal passport this needs to be stamped. I had this issue today. I had to cut a bit of the laminate off so it could be stamped. The need for the birth certificate is eliminated when you are granted your internal passport.